# Epub.js Usage in Ionic

Tags: ionic2, epub.js

I am trying to make an app which can open to read epub files. So I have tried to import this [Epub.js javascript library](https://github.com/futurepress/epub.js) according to this [article](https://x-team.com/blog/include-javascript-libraries-in-an-ionic-2-typescript-project/). I am done with the arrangements in the article. So with code below I am trying to use epub.js in my Ionic 2 app in windows 10 and chrome browser. But I am getting this error below. Why am I getting this error?

ecatalog.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {epubjs} from "epubjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-ecatalog',
  templateUrl: 'ecatalog.html'

})
export class EcatalogPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    var Book = epubjs.ePub("../www/books/k1ecatalog.epub");
      Book.renderTo("area");
  }
}
```

ecatalog.html

```
<ion-content>
<div onclick="Book.prevPage();">‹</div>
<div id="area"></div>
<div onclick="Book.nextPage();">›</div>

</ion-content>
```

Error:

```
Runtime Error
Error in ./MyApp class MyApp - caused by: Cannot read property 'ePub' of undefined

Stack
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ePub' of undefined
    at new EcatalogPage (http ://192.16 8.33.11:8100/build/main.js:58587:66)
    at new Wrapper_EcatalogPage (/AppModule/EcatalogPage/wrapper.ngfactory.js:7:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_EcatalogPage_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/EcatalogPage/host.ngfactory.js:15:26)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (http: //192 .168.33.11:8100/build/main.js:99490:21)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy **epubjs** folder into **src/assets** and then reference necessary 
files in your **src/index.html**

```
<script src="assets/epubjs/build/epub.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/epubjs/build/libs/zip.min.js"></script>
```

and then in you page:

```
declare var ePub: any;
let book = ePub("assets/books/moby-dick/");
```

https://github.com/janpio/ionic-epubjs

Comment: Thanks. But how to load epub from sdcard location?